# Building hibernate-orm from source hangs

Tags: hibernate, gradle

I am having issues building a fresh checkout of hibernate-orm. Basically I'm following the instructions from [Contribute to Hibernate ORM](http://hibernate.org/orm/contribute/). First I clone the current trunk from github:

```
git clone git@github.com:hibernate/hibernate-orm.git
```

After that I start the gradle build:

```
gradlew clean build
```

My machine setup is:

- Windows 7 64bit
- JDK 1.7.0_07

During the execution of the test task of the module hibernate-core the build process stops and hangs there forever. One of the tests fails as well, but that seems to be a known issue. My real problem is that the build does not continue - even after several hours there's no progress anymore - the build process just hangs. I see the following console output:

```
Maven settings.xml file did not exist : C:\Users\dajudge\.m2\settings.xml
:documentation:clean
:hibernate-c3p0:clean
:hibernate-core:clean
:hibernate-ehcache:clean UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin:clean UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-entitymanager:clean UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-envers:clean UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-gradle-plugin:clean UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-hikaricp:clean UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-infinispan:clean UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-jpamodelgen:clean UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-osgi:clean UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-proxool:clean UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-testing:clean
:release:clean
:documentation:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:documentation:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:documentation:classes UP-TO-DATE
:documentation:jar
:documentation:assemble
:documentation:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:documentation:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:documentation:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:documentation:test UP-TO-DATE
:documentation:check UP-TO-DATE
:documentation:build
:hibernate-c3p0:copyJavaApiSignature
:hibernate-c3p0:runSourceGenerators UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-core:copyJavaApiSignature
:hibernate-core:generateGrammarSource
[ant:null] ANTLR Parser Generator   Version 2.7.7 (20060906)   1989-2005
[ant:null] ANTLR Parser Generator   Version 2.7.7 (20060906)   1989-2005
[ant:null] ANTLR Parser Generator   Version 2.7.7 (20060906)   1989-2005
[ant:null] ANTLR Parser Generator   Version 2.7.7 (20060906)   1989-2005
[ant:null] ANTLR Parser Generator   Version 2.7.7 (20060906)   1989-2005
[ant:null] ANTLR Parser Generator   Version 2.7.7 (20060906)   1989-2005
:hibernate-core:jaxb
:hibernate-core:runSourceGenerators
:hibernate-core:compileJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:hibernate-core:processResources
:hibernate-core:classes
:hibernate-core:jar
:hibernate-c3p0:compileJava
:hibernate-c3p0:processResources
:hibernate-c3p0:classes
:hibernate-c3p0:jar
:hibernate-c3p0:assemble
:hibernate-c3p0:checkstyleMain
:hibernate-c3p0:findbugsMain
FindBugs rule violations were found. See the report at: file:///D:/git/github/hibernate-orm/hibernate-c3p0/target/reports/findbugs/main.xml
:hibernate-c3p0:runTestSourceGenerators UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-testing:copyJavaApiSignature
:hibernate-testing:runSourceGenerators UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-testing:compileJava
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:hibernate-testing:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-testing:classes
:hibernate-testing:jar
:hibernate-c3p0:compileTestJava
Note: D:\git\github\hibernate-orm\hibernate-c3p0\src\test\java\org\hibernate\test\c3p0\C3P0ConnectionProviderTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:hibernate-c3p0:processTestResources
:hibernate-c3p0:testClasses
:hibernate-c3p0:findbugsTest
:hibernate-c3p0:test
:hibernate-c3p0:buildDashboard
:hibernate-c3p0:check
:hibernate-c3p0:build
:hibernate-core:assemble
:hibernate-core:checkstyleMain
Checkstyle rule violations were found. See the report at: file:///D:/git/github/hibernate-orm/hibernate-core/target/reports/checkstyle/main.xml
:hibernate-core:findbugsMain
FindBugs rule violations were found. See the report at: file:///D:/git/github/hibernate-orm/hibernate-core/target/reports/findbugs/main.xml
:hibernate-core:generateTestGrammarSource UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-core:runTestSourceGenerators UP-TO-DATE
:hibernate-core:compileTestJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:hibernate-core:processTestResources
:hibernate-core:testClasses
:hibernate-core:findbugsTest
FindBugs rule violations were found. See the report at: file:///D:/git/github/hibernate-orm/hibernate-core/target/reports/findbugs/test.xml
:hibernate-core:test

org.hibernate.test.fileimport.MultiLineImportFileTest > testImportFile FAILED
    org.junit.ComparisonFailure at MultiLineImportFileTest.java:83
> Building > :hibernate-core:test > 1929 tests completed, 1 failed, 81 skipped
```

At this point the build process hangs forever and I see 3 java processes in the task monitor:

- The gradle process itself
- 2 more java processes (probably test runners?)

Digging the interwebs didn't bring up anything useful, so I'm turning to the stackoverflow community with the question:

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? How can I successfully build hibernate-orm from source?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the quick help from the #hibernate-dev IRC channel I as able to resolve the issue. It turns out this is a known issue for hibernate-orm master at the moment. Skipping the offending batch of tests with the following build command fixes the hang-up issue:

```
gradlew build -Dhibernate.test.validatefailureexpected=false
```